# How can I run updates in batches in Rails 3/4?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I need to mass-update many thousands of records, and I would like to process the updates in batches. First, I tried:

```
Foo.where(bar: 'bar').find_in_batches.update_all(bar: 'baz')
```

...which I was hoping would generate SQL such as:

```
"UPDATE foo SET bar = 'baz' where bar='bar' AND id > (whatever id is passed in by find_in_batches)"
```

That doesn't work because find_in_batches returns an array, while update_all needs an ActiveRecord relation.

This is what I tried next:

```
Foo.where(bar: 'bar').select('id').find_in_batches do |foos|
  ids = foos.map(&:id)
  Foo.where(id: ids).update_all(bar: 'baz')
end
```

That works, but it obviously runs a select followed by the update, rather than a single update based on my 'where' conditions. Is there any way to clean this up, so that the select and update don't have to be separate queries?

Comment: but y do you have to do that update in batches? how many rows does your where clause yield?

Comment: The where clause will retrieve hundreds of thousands of records, which is why I am using find_in_batches to process the updates in batches of 1000 at a time.

Comment: Same question as Marian, I don't get your reasoning. If you do Foo.where().update_all it will not load records to Rails, just perform a db update query.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel, I am performing the update in batches to avoid locking my table while updating hundreds of thousands of records.

Answer (score 91):

In Rails 5, there's a new handy method `ActiveRecord::Relation#in_batches` to solve this problem:

```
Foo.in_batches.update_all(bar: 'baz')
```

Check [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-in_batches) for details.

Comment: Use this gem [in_batches](https://github.com/khiav223577/in_batches) to use this handy method in rails 3/4.

Answer (score 12):

I'm surprised, too, that there isn't an easier way to do this... but I did come up with this approach:

```
batch_size = 1000
0.step(Foo.count, batch_size).each do |offset|
  Foo.where(bar: 'bar').order(:id)
                       .offset(offset)
                       .limit(batch_size)
                       .update_all(bar: 'baz')
end
```

Basically this will:

1. Create an array of offsets between `0` and `Foo.count` stepping by `batch_size` each time. For example, if `Foo.count == 10500` you'd get: `[0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000]`
2. Loop through these numbers and use them as an OFFSET in the SQL query, being sure to order by `id`, and limiting to the `batch_size`.
3. Update at most `batch_size` records whose "index" is greater than `offset`.

This is basically the manual way to perform what you said you were hoping for in the generated SQL. Too bad it can't just be done this way already by a standard library method... though I'm sure you could create one of your own.

Comment: for me, this did not work exactly as specified (didn't get all the records updated in the first run) so I wrapped in a while statement which did process until done: `query = -> { Foo.where(conditions).count } ; while (count = query.call) > 0 ; #run above ; end`

Comment: This unfortunately won't work because Rails doesn't support `offset` with `update_all`, see here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10849

Comment: This only works if you're iterating over the entire table. This won't work if you're trying to update a hundred million rows of a table that has half a billion records.

Answer (score 10):

This is 2 years late, but the answers here are a) very slow for large data sets and b) ignore the builtin rails capabilities (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html).

As the offset value increases, depending on your DB server, it will do a sequence scan until it reaches your block, and then fetches the data for processing. As your offset gets into the millions, this will be *extremely* slow.

use the "find_each" iterator method:

```
Foo.where(a: b).find_each do |bar|
   bar.x = y
   bar.save
end
```

This has the added benefit of running the model callbacks with each save. If you don't care for the callbacks, then try:

```
Foo.where(a: b).find_in_batches do |array_of_foo|
  ids = array_of_foo.collect &:id
  Foo.where(id: ids).update_all(x: y)
end
```

Comment: The find_each does not use offset internaly?

Comment: @Naremy no. find_each would run a query and adds `where id > X order by id asc limit 1000`. As it iterates over the batch, it keeps updating the id to the latest id and then issues a new call. This way it never uses offset (which gets progressively slow as it needs to load all data before any offset operation is done)

Comment: There's no need for `ids = array_of_foo.collect &:id`. You can pass an array of objects into a `where` clause like so:
`Foo.where(id: array_of_foo).update_all(x: y)`

Answer (score 4):

pdobb's answer is on the right track, but didn't work for me in Rails 3.2.21 because of this issue of ActiveRecord not parsing OFFSET with UPDATE calls:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10849

I modified the code accordingly and it worked fine for concurrently setting the default value on my Postgres table:

```
batch_size = 1000
0.step(Foo.count, batch_size).each do |offset|
  Foo.where('id > ? AND id <= ?', offset, offset + batch_size).
      order(:id).
      update_all(foo: 'bar')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't had a chance to test this yet but you might be able to use ARel and a sub query.

```
Foo.where(bar: 'bar').select('id').find_in_batches do |foos|
  Foo.where( Foo.arel_table[ :id ].in( foos.to_arel ) ).update_all(bar: 'baz')
end
```