# Rails Active Record - Creating a column from other column values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, sqlite

Suppose I have a User model in my database, with height and weight of each user already inputted. Now I want to add a BMI column in the user table, calculated from the weight and height of each existing user. What would be the most efficient way to do that if I had a million users?

P.S

I've tried adding a rails route that runs the script locally when called, but found it takes to long. I don't think I could use rails console as it requires a complex method.

Comment: Do you want an actual column in the database with just the calculation for migrated data, or do you just want a readonly attribute on the model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run updates in batches in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252811/how-can-i-run-updates-in-batches-in-rails)

Comment: @Ilya Definitely not, this explains how to run updates in batches, I wanted to know how to create a column based of values from other columns.

Comment: @Isaac, you can create a column and then update all values in batches.

Answer (score 1):

you can use update_all, this update through database NOT looping through all record
[api documentation for update_all](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all)

```
User.update_all('bmi = height * weight')
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need a migration to add the column, but don't set a default (setting a default can take a long time when you have a ton of records)

add_column :some_attribute, :string

After the column is there, you need to backfill it.

Use `find_each`. 1,000,000 users is going to take some time to process no matter what you do. Using `find_each` insures that they will only be instantiated 1,000 at a time.

```
User.find_each do |user|
  num = user.height * user.width # or whatever you need to figure out here
  user.update_attributes(some_attribute: num)
end
```

You could set up an endpoint that kicks the `find_each` off, but really, you're best off running it via console. I'd use `screen` since it has the potential to be a long-running process.

You could put that in a migration file instead, but there are varying opinions regarding whether or not its best practice to manipulate data in migrations.

Answer (score -1):

So if you want to add BMI to each existing user, maybe the best way is to create `rake task`, where you would add logic for updating that column.

Assume you already added new column `bmi` to user model which is integer, then you need rake task:

```
namespace :user do
  task :bmi_calculator => 'environment' do
    User.find_each do |user|
      bmi = user.height/user.weight (I'm not sure about computation)
      user.update_attribute(bmi: bmi)
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can run this task (`rake user:bmi_calculator`) whenever you want! Also, my advice is to use some cron job for this kind of task to run automatically after midnight when traffic is not so big.

Cheers